# Angular 2, Media Queries not working when combined with [ngStyle] directive

Tags: css, angular, media-queries

I have set some custom attributes on a div

```
 <div class="logout-container"

             [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': (theme.logoutButtonMarginLeft | convertpx ),
                     'margin-top': (theme.logoutButtonMarginTop | convertpx ),
                     'margin-right': (theme.logoutButtonMarginRight | convertpx ) }"
```

I am also using Media Queries to set the value for smaller screen sizes. The idea being to maintain a certain look and feel for smaller devices but allow the user some freedom on larger screens.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 1px) {

.logout-container {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

}

However the above media queries have no effect and the margin values stay constant through all screen sizes. Using a different style syntax has no effect either. Thus using

```
<div class="logout-container"
             [style.margin-top.px]="theme.logoutButtonMarginTop"
             [style.margin-left.px]="theme.logoutButtonMarginLeft"
             [style.margin-right.px]="theme.logoutButtonMarginRight"
```

will not allow the media queries to take affect either.

Comment: the style you are applying on element have first priority and css have second check out through inspect element you will see media query styles are stroked.

Comment: are you saying what Im trying to achieve is Not possible because media styles have second priority and as such will never work?

Comment: for example if you use `color: red` in inline style and wrote same in css file `color: green` the element will be colored `red` not `green` because it will go for inline for external css you have to use `!important` to force apply to element its a bit tricky you have to handle it logically

Comment: Ok I think I understand, and your solution has worked. Adding !important to the end worked
   

  
        margin-right: 20px  !important;

Answer (score 0):

- Inline css have 1st priotity
- Internal css have second priority
- External css have last priority
- In internal/external css `@media` query have priority.

You can force a style to apply on element using `!important` keyword.